# Promise.all/for await and fetch array of queries for it

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Can i

```
array.push(fetch(`something`))
```

For execution in Promise.all / for await, or

```
fetch(`something`)
```

execute itself before i push it in array and not further in code when i want it?

---

More info:

Let assume i need to do many queries with for await (if i want to execute them one after another) or Promise.all (if i want to execute them async together).

I make an queries array:

```
let queries = []
let allResults = []
```

Push there promises:

```
tiersQueries.push(fetch(`something`))
```

And them execute it like this:

```
for await (const oneResult of queries) {
 allResults.push(oneResult)
}
```

Or this:

```
let results = await Promise.all(array)
allResults = results
```

Comment: `fetch()` returns a promise and does not wait for anything.

Comment: so data fetching at this point already started?

Comment: Yeah, it's already started

Comment: you can store all the api links in an array and then loop on that Array to store the result in another array of all the fetch responses. Then after that, fetch responses further return Promises, so these can be handled by Promise.all();

Comment: I think you just have to wrap something and it will work out. I suggest you to bring up the real code (more than yet, as a working unit, not everything ofc, but relevant part..), so you can show where's exactly your problem. Coders like code.

Comment: Your first approach is basically `Promise.all` in 3 lines of code, 4 if you count initializing the result array.

Comment: @SilvanBregy done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245587/how-to-make-array-of-queries-for-for-await-loop

Answer (score 0):

The way promises work, they will immediately start executing when created, but they store their status (resolved or rejected or pending) so that even `.then` or `.catch` handlers attached after they are completed will still fire. Similarly, `Promise.all` just waits for all the promises to be resolved, it doesn't care whether they were resolved before you passed them `.all`. That means you're perfectly fine pushing all the fetches to an array and using `Promise.all` to attach resolution handlers for processing the results of all of them whenever they complete (even if they all complete before the `.all` runs).