# Array of queries for `for await` loop for postgresql transaction helper

Tags: javascript, postgresql, es6-promise

I made a transaction function that simplifies this action for me like this (it working):

```
export async function transaction(queriesRaw) {
  let allResults = []

  const client = await pool.connect()

  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')
    var queries = queriesRaw.map(q => {
      return client.query(q[0], q[1])
    })

    for await (const oneResult of queries) {
      allResults.push(oneResult)
    }
    await client.query('COMMIT')
  } catch (err) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK')
  } finally {
    client.release()
    return allResults
  }
}
```

And do transactions like this:

```
let results = await transaction([
            ['UPDATE readers SET cookies=5 WHERE id=$1;', [1]],
            ['INSERT INTO rewards (id) VALUES ($1);', [3]]
          ])
```

Transaction should do queries one at a time in array index sequence (so rollback to previos values will work correctly) and return in the same order (sometimes i need return values from some queries)

As i understand it starts already in map map function. In for await i just wait for results of it and second query may complete faster that previos.

So how can i fix this?

P.S. Maybe something like new Promise() instead map is the rigth way?

Comment: I'm sorry, just for understand, these are SQL that will run to your RDBMS?

Comment: Yep, Postgresql

Comment: Both, because somethimes i return values from some of queries.

Comment: You should use `Promise.all()` instead of your loop.

Comment: @SLaks Promise.all does not await and i need it in transaction.

Comment: i think issue might be that you are doing the `map` and effectively creating a number of `promise` objects. Why not `foreach` the raw array and `await` the result?

Comment: @Bibberty so how then create array of promises for for await loop?

Comment: @RTW: You should write `allResults = await Promise.all(queries)`

Comment: To run async code in sequence instead of in parallel, see https://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/#sequential-operations

Comment: @SLaks Promise.all start execution of all queries at the SAME time and for transaction rollback it's not usable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697719/sequential-promises-using-async-await-in-vanilla-javascript

Comment: Can i just raise a red flag here? You are exposing and sending sql commands directly is a bad idea, can expose your database and make it easy to inject SQL. maybe at least you can encrypt the texts?

Comment: @Marco how else can you send your sql commands to db :) $1 is protecting me for inject of untrusted values.

Comment: Nice, just a reminder :)

Comment: @Marco: There is nothing wrong with exposing SQL in server-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you correctly, Just use a for loop with proper `await`, instead of a callback style loop.

So you can wait with the function to return unil everything is chronologically executed, With some thinking, you can easily add aa revoke() function or something..

```
...
export async function transaction(queriesRaw) {
  let allResults = []

  const client = await pool.connect()

  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')

    for(var i = 0; i < queriesRaw.length;i++) {
        var res = await client.query(queriesRaw[i][0], queriesRaw[i][1])
        allResults.push(res)
    }

    await client.query('COMMIT')
  } catch (err) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK') 

    // do you maybe wanna errors to results to?
    // allResults.push(err)
  } finally {
    client.release()
    return allResults
  }
}
```

#### Info,

Have a look at for example [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, or something similar. So you will not have to think about things like this.

Comment: I am, and just try it..     For explanation,  You cannot use `await` within `forEach` because you pass a new function to it. So for having `await` in `forEach` you do this: `[fetch()].forEach(async res => console.log(await res))`. But then you'll have a problem because your code does not wait for the `forEach` to finish it's iterations. Read this:  https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Comment: thanks, for some reason this simple solution didn't get in my head as i was trying to make for await work :/

Comment: That's why you should talk to other coders about your problems^^

Comment: It's solves my problem, but still question remains, how to make array of promises for new for await loop :)

Comment: I don't know either. I think you would have to use a generator: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function* ,  And here's an example of await for loop :: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: The link pointing on `/function`  should be `/function*`, with `*`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
var queries = queriesRaw.map(q => {
  return client.query(q[0], q[1])
})

for await (const oneResult of queries) {
  allResults.push(oneResult)
}
```

To:

```
for(const q of rawQueries) {
   let result = await client.query(q[0], q[1]);
   allResults.push(result);
});
```